# .on jquery method and button dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning I have a problem with jQuery .on(). my JavaScript says

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button[name='modificaProva']").on("click",function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        if($('#gestioneProva').is(":visible")){
            $('#gestioneProva').slideToggle();
        }
        else{
            var provaSelected=$("input[name='provaSelected']:checked").val();
            var idProva=parseInt(provaSelected);
            if(isNaN(idProva)){
                alert("L' id della prova selezionato risulta non essere un numero. Prova a riaggiornare la pagina e se l'errore persiste contatta un amministratore");
            }
            else{
                getDettagliProva(idProva);
            }
        }
   });
});
```

my HTML says:

```
<p class="submitProve"><button type="button" name="creaProva">Crea Prova</button></p>
```

then I need to add dynamically a button called "modificaProva" and I use this code:

```
$(".submitProve").append('<button type="button" name="modificaProva">Mostra/Nascondi Dettagli Prova</button>');
```

The button was added after some other stuff,it appears on the screen in the correct position but when I click on it nothing appends. If I create the button when the page loads all works fine.The method on must work also if the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a dynamically created element, you must use event delegation like below:

```
$(".submitProve").on("click","button[name='modificaProva']", function (event) {
    //rest of your onclick event code.
});
```

**Note:** We are delegating from `.submitProve` because it is the closest static element. If it is not static, you can delegate from `$(document)`.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6pC7/)

More information on delegation could be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation, delegate event to parent or document to bind event to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on("click", "button[name='modificaProva']", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if($('#gestioneProva').is(":visible")){
        $('#gestioneProva').slideToggle();
    }
    else{
    var provaSelected=$("input[name='provaSelected']:checked").val();
    var idProva=parseInt(provaSelected);
    if(isNaN(idProva)){
        alert("L' id della prova selezionato risulta non essere un numero. Prova a riaggiornare la pagina e se l'errore persiste contatta un amministratore");
    }
    else{
    getDettagliProva(idProva);
    }
 }});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

For the new created button you need to change `.on()` to `.live()` like this:

```
$('button[name="modificaProva"]').live('click', function(){
   ... your code
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. Please don't use.